# what is meant by the term webometrics

Tags: web

I have come across the term Webometrics.Actually the term Webmetrics has been used in my application. Are the two terms different from each other. If same could someone explain this term. If different please explain me Webmetrics in detail. I have gone through the wikipedia source but didn't get the concept clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The science of webometrics  (also cybermetrics ) tries to measure the
>   World Wide Web to get knowledge about the number and types of
>   hyperlinks, structure of the World Wide Web and usage patterns.
>   According to Björneborn and Ingwersen (2004), the definition of
>   webometrics  is "the study of the quantitative aspects of the
>   construction and use of information resources, structures and
>   technologies on the Web drawing on bibliometric and informetric
>   approaches." The term webometrics  was first coined by Almind and
>   Ingwersen (1997). Similar scientific fields are Bibliometrics,
>   Informetrics, Scientometrics, Virtual ethnography, and Web mining.

[Webometrics](http://www.reference.com/browse/Webometrics?s=t)

There is a bit more about it over here:

[More about](http://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00176ED1V01Y200903ICR004)

Comment: The More about link is good one. I am satisfied with the answer.